# Remove an element from JList

Tags: java, swing, exception, jlist

I try to remove selected element from jList, and get exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:447)
        at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.remove(DefaultListModel.java:493)
        at gui.Back.jButton2ActionPerformed(Back.java:410)
        at gui.Back.access$300(Back.java:9)
        at gui.Back$5.actionPerformed(Back.java:146)
```

My code:

```
DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();
//System.out.println(dlm.getSize());
dlm.remove(jList1.getSelectedIndex()); //removeElementAt(int i) don't work too
jList1.setModel(dlm);
```

It's strange, because dlm.getSize(); returns 2.

What I've doing wrong?

Comment: Modifying the GUI elements must be done from EDT. Is  that the case?

Comment: Its difficult to give an answer that will be helpful because the 3 lines of code posted doesn't reflect the cause of the exception.

Comment: getSize can't be returning 2. If it was, the exception wouldn't say 1 >= 0.  If getSize really is returning 2, maybe there is another thread that is removing elements from the same list?

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do it is as follows:

`final int index = mylist.getSelectedIndex();`

if (index >= 0) {
    ((DefaultListModel) mylist.getModel()).removeElementAt(index); 
}

You don't need to re-set the ListModel again once data has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Read the JList API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Lists" for a working example that does this.

Then compare your code with the working code to see what the difference is.

We can't tell you the problem based on a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced this issue multiple times.  Inspection at variable breakpoints reveal the returned `index value < (size - 1)`, so within parameters that would NOT expect to throw an `IOOB Exception`.  I haven't been able to figure out the cause.

However, I have managed an acceptable workaround, which is to keep my own external model of the the data in an `ArrayList` and edit that.  Then, convert to an array and update through the `list.setListData()` method.  Not very efficient, but functional and the only way I've found to completely preserve the integrity of the data.